# Flatmap and rdd while keeping the rest of the entry

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working in spark and I have an Rdd of the form:

```
(x_{11},x_{12}, x_{13}, Array(A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}))
(x_{21},x_{22}, x_{23}, Array(A_{1},A_{2}))
(x_{31},x_{32}, x_{33}, Array(A_{1}))
```

I want to flatten the Array values while keeping the x values. I understand if I had just the arrays, I could do df.flatmap and get one Array element per line but what I would like to do is get

```
(x_{11},x_{12}, x_{13}, A_{1})
(x_{11},x_{12}, x_{13}, A_{2})
(x_{11},x_{12}, x_{13}, A_{3})
(x_{21},x_{22}, x_{23}, A_{1})
(x_{21},x_{22}, x_{23}, A_{2})
(x_{31},x_{32}, x_{33}, A_{1})
```

Essentially what I want is to repeat the row for each item in the Array. How can I go about doing this in Spark-Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`, just make sure that the function you pass preserves the "prefix" columns for all values in the list:

```
val input: RDD[(Int, Int, Int, Seq[String])] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 2, 3, Seq("a", "b")),
  (5, 6, 7, Seq("c", "d", "e"))
))

val result: RDD[(Int, Int, Int, String)] = 
  input.flatMap { case (i1, i2, i3, list) => list.map(e => (i1, i2, i3, e)) }

/* result:
   (1,2,3,a)
   (1,2,3,b)
   (5,6,7,c)
   (5,6,7,d)
   (5,6,7,e)
*/
```